# regex in ubuntu to exclude a file named 0 specifically

Tags: regex, grep

I have the following file names:

```
1
2
3
4
0
0.1
0.2
1e-0.3
1e-3
a
v
```

I am using Ubuntu, and would like to grep all numeric values except the value 0.

I tried `ls | grep -E '[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?'` and it gets all numerical entries with the exponential.

But I would like to exclude the file named 0. Only the 0, and not 0.1 or 0.2

The desired output is:

```
1
2
3
4
0.1
0.2
1e-0.3
1e-3
```

Where all numeric files are listed except the file 0.

Best Regards

Comment: I suggest: `| awk '$0+0'`

Comment: Or `awk '+$0' file` if OP doesn't want to match regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your shown samples, could you please try following. Try with `find` command.

```
find . -regextype egrep -regex '.*/([-+]?((([1-8]+{1,}|[0-9]{2,})(\.[0-9]+)?)|(0+\.[0-9]+))|([0-9]+[eE][-+]?([0-9]+?(\.[0-9]+)?))?)$'
```

Let's say we have following files(test purposes):

```
1
4
3
2
0.1
0
1e-3
1e-0.3
0.2
```

After running code we will get following files.

```
./4
./2
./1e-3
./1e-0.3
./0.2
./3
./1
./0.1
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
.*/    ##Matching till last slash here.
(
  [-+]?((([1-8]+{1,}|[0-9]{2,})(\.[0-9]+)?)|(0+\.[0-9]+))
       ##Matching file names which starts from +or- and not have only 0 in their name(could have float numbers also optional).
  |    ##putting OR condition
  ([0-9]+[eE][-+]?([0-9]+?(\.[0-9]+)?))?
       ##Matching file names which have 1e-03 OR 1e+3 like names here.
)$
```

Comment: Is the a problem with doing ` ls | grep `?

Comment: @ManuelOliveira, yeah experts never advise to do so, please see this thread once https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead thank you.

Comment: is it possible to strip the name of the folder?

Answer (score 1):

You may use `awk` **without** using any regex:

```sh
find . -type f -maxdepth 1 | awk -F/ '+$2'

./1
./2
./3
./4
./0.1
./0.2
./1e-0.3
./1e-3
```

Here, `-F/` sets delimiter as `/` and `$2` gets us the filename. Then condition `+$2` returns true if `$2` is numeric and `> 0`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need two things:

In order to skip, you need "grep -v".

The filename 0 contains three characters:

- beginning of line
- the 0 character
- end of line

I think that beginning of line is "$", and end of line is "%", so you do something like:

```
grep -v "$0%"
```

You also need to do "ls" getting every filename on another line.